# How to pass a column of pandas data frame as input to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want inputvalues inside a column of pandas dataframe as input another to a dataframe for dropping columns.

#### Corpus words

```
corpus_top_words = pd.DataFrame(cv_addr.todense(), columns=cv.get_feature_names())
corpus_top_words  =corpus_top_words.sum().rename_axis('Word').reset_index(name='Freq')
corpus_top_words=corpus_top_words.drop('Freq', axis=1)
```

#### English Dictionary

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
    word_list=list(brown.words())
    feature_names=['Word']
    word_list= pd.DataFrame(word_list,columns=feature_names)
    brown_corpus=pd.DataFrame(word_list.Word.unique(),columns=feature_names)
    brown_corpus['Word'] = brown_corpus['Word'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item.lower() for item in x.split()]))
```

#### Only English Words

```
english_words_corpus = pd.merge(corpus_top_words, brown_corpus, on='Word', how='inner')
english_words_corpus = pd.DataFrame(english_words_corpus.Word.unique(),columns=feature_names)
```

I need to pass this english word corpus to the orginal dataframe to remove some columns:

```
data = data.drop(list_of_cols_to_drop, axis=1)

list_of_cols_to_drop = english_words_corpus
```

How this for sparse series

```
for i, col in enumerate(cv.get_feature_names()):
data[col] = pd.SparseSeries(cv_text[:, i].toarray().ravel(), fill_value=0)
```

Comment: @Stephen Rauch,Sorry about it

Answer (score 0):

To drop columns which match a list you can do this:

```
data = data.drop([col for col in list_of_cols_to_drop if col in data.columns], axis=1)
```

Comment: is there way i can remove it from sparse series                                           
      for i, col in enumerate(cv.get_feature_names()):
    data[col] = pd.SparseSeries(cv_addr[:, i].toarray().ravel(), fill_value=0)

Comment: @ashokeapen, You are changing the question after it was answered?